# Communicating with sensor(ethernet static IP) via raspberry pi

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I am new to writing and understanding code. I have been reading for the past week different ways to approach the task at hand, but I am running into a few problems. The sensor I am currently using is connected via ethernet and take commands via bytes. The sensor is currently set up in that it is constantly streaming data via ethernet (IP 192.168.60.3 port 9008). I am trying to set up a socket in python to communicate to the sensor but I end up getting connection refused. Is there a way to listen and record the incoming data from the ethernet? I can ping the sensors IP and can see responses roughly every second back.

I have the data sheet with command bytes for the sensor but I am unsure how to communicate with it specifically. It accepts these commands and will respond with answers. But I dont know how to establish a connection with it at first. There is a command 0x434E that is to connect to sensor. But how do I transfer that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I will be happy to answer any questions that I can.

[Sensor link](http://www.leuze.com/en/deutschland/produkte/messende_sensoren/3d_sensoren_1/lichtschnittsensoren_1/lps_5/selector.php?supplier_aid=50111325&grp_id=A1-2-3-1&lang=eng#%7B"tab":"2"%7D)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Comment: this sounds like a LUX sensor ... I made a logger for one of those not so long ago... Im not sure how common of a protocol this is... but I definitely used sockets when I was talking to the lux

Comment: also you should probably include a link to the datasheet or at the very least the sensor name...

Comment: That would have been the obvious thing to do. I have added a link above to the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

If you get "connection refused", you are using TCP. In the page you link to it clearly says it uses UDP (UDP has no concept of a connection). Also read carefully how to configure the response ports (there is probably both a local and remote port to configure, the remote port of the sensor must match the listening port on your Pi).